# Code highlighting messes up formatting for long input code

Tags: r-markdown

I have observed this weird issue where a long string in input code creates messy formatting. See example below.

[image]

A horizontal scrollbar is added and text continues outside the div. After a lot of trial and error, I have narrowed the issue down to the `highlight:` parameter. This happens when `highlight:` is set to `espresso`, `haddock`, `kate`, `pygments`, `tango` or `zenburn`. The full Rmd code for the above output is here:

````
---
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    highlight: tango
---

```{r,echo=TRUE}
cat("install.packages(c('devtools','dplyr','enrichR','ggplot2','ggpubr','knitr','markdown','pheatmap','pvclust','rafalib','rmarkdown','stringr','tidyr'))")
```
````

For comparison, here is an example where `highlight: textmate` is used. It works as expected.

[image]